# Time series update to mongodb using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wish to update my mongoDB for a particular functionality in a similar way mentioned in this blog: 
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Following is how I want my database table to look like:

```
{
  _id : Object("5aab763d455a20153c05f024"),
  mapped_id : "5aaa21bdbf3dce44c41f1ba9",
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2018-03-29T11:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: { 0: 123, 15: 213, 30: 563, 45: 784},
    1: { 0: 134, 15: 632, 30: 489, 45: 893},
    …,
    58: { 0: 309, 15: 432, 30: 203, 45: 398},
    59: { 0: 123, 15: 209, 30: 290, 45: 432}
  }
}
```

for which I have implemented the following:

```
var someFunction = function(){

var dateTime = new Date();
var values = {};
values[dateTime.getMinutes()] = {};
values[dateTime.getMinutes()][dateTime.getSeconds()] = "some random integer";

var myQuery = { mapped_id : DocumentID.toString() }; //some other Document in a collection.
var newValues = { $set : {values} };

}

setInterval(function(){

    someFunction();

}, 15000);
```

to which I am only able to get something like this:

```
{
  _id : Object("5aab763d455a20153c05f024"),
  mapped_id : "5aaa21bdbf3dce44c41f1ba9",
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2018-03-29T11:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    58: { 15: 432}
  }
}
```

I am only able to get one object value, which gets updated to the next value on update.

Comment: In your function you start with a _clean/new_ `values` variable in which you set only one value. You should populate it with the values that you already have and then append the value and store it, or use an insert construction for the values in the document instead of _overwriting_ it with your new `values` variable.

Comment: Thanks. Found no other work around but to start with clean variables and append it and then flush them to the database.